# PHP-FPM + nginx 1.1.15 Custom error pages

Tags: nginx, php

I have a PHP-FPM configured as backend for nginx 1.1.15.
I need to customize 40x, 50x error pages for errors coming from PPH-FPM.

For example, I send 403 header from php script and want nginx to show custom page.
nginx configured as follows:

```
    error_page  403 /403.html;
    location = /403.html {
        root   html;
        allow  all;
    }
```

But when I send 403 header from php, nginx shows it's native "403 Forbidden" page, not my custom.

Upd: I'm sorry. I didn't give full config of nginx.
I handle 404 in nginx and pass all queries to a single script. This script sends 403 headers. So nginx not display custom 403 page. When I request an existing script, to bypass the 404 rule in nginx conf, then custom error page is returned. Here is a part of my nginx.conf

```
    error_page 404 = @myhandler;

    location @myhandler {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME script.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    error_page  403 /403.html;
    location = /403.html {
        root   html;
        allow  all;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
```

UPD: I've found a solution.

```
**recursive_error_pages on;**
error_page 404 = @myhandler;

location @myhandler {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME script.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    **error_page  403 /403.html;**
}
```